# (RLE) How to get the numbers in front instead of letters

Tags: java

I am having problems displaying my output. I want to print out so that it shows the number first instead of the letter. For example, when I type in "WWWHJJJ" it comes out "W3HJ3" and I want it to come out "3WH3J" instead.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompressString {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter string: ");
      String str = sc.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Entered input: " + str);


      String encode = "";

      char ch=0;
      int count=1;

      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
      {
         if (ch == str.charAt(i))
         {
            count = count + 1;
         }
         else
         {
            encode = encode + ch;
            if(count != 1)
            {
               encode = encode + count;
            }

            ch = str.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
         }
      }
      encode = encode + ch;
      if(count != 1)
      {
         encode = encode + count;
      }
      System.out.println("Encoded: " + encode);
   }
}
```

Comment: Best way to solve this is to use your IDE's debugger to see what is happening to the state of the program as it runs.

Comment: I would also use a StringBuilder instead of string concatenation. the StringBuilder is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonably obvious that this:

```
        encode = encode + ch;
        if(count != 1)
        {
           encode = encode + count;
        }
```

Appends the character and then the count. Just reverse the order:

```
        if(count != 1)
        {
           encode = encode + count;
        }
        encode = encode + ch;
```